# Double complex of simplicial resolution

Tags: homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff, condensed-mathematics

In his
[lectures on condensed mathematics](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf) on page 30 Peter Scholze speaks of the double complex of a simplicial resolution. How is this defined?

In the next line, he writes that if $A_\bullet$ is a resolution of an abelian group, then ${\mathbb Z}[A_\bullet]$ is one for ${\mathbb Z}[A]$ which looks like he is saying that the functor $A\mapsto {\mathbb Z}[A]$ is exact, which wouldn't make sense, as this functor isn't additive and it doesn't preserve complexes.

If one takes the comonad resolution given by $A_0={\mathbb Z}[A]$ and $A_{k+1}={\mathbb Z}[A_k]$, then ${\mathbb Z}[A_\bullet]=A_{\bullet+1}$ is a resolution for ${\mathbb Z}[A]$, but the differentials are different.

I guess my questions are:

1. What is the double complex to a simplicial resolution?
2. What does Scholze mean when he writes "The resulting double complex is equivalent to the complex for A" ? What complex for $A$ is meant here?

Comment: They mean the complex displayed on the top of the page; viewed as a map $C^\bullet(A) \to A[0]$ that they want to show is a quasi-isomorphism. The complex $C^\bullet(A)$ is functorial in $A$, so you cannot only apply it to an abelian group $A$ but also to any diagram of abelian groups; for instance a simplicial resolution. This gives a simplicial complex $C^\bullet(A_\bullet)$, which is turned into a (third quadrant) double complex by the usual construction (the easy direction of Dold–Kan). Then the totalisation of this double complex maps quasi-isomorphically to $C^\bullet(A)$.

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn Great! Thanks. That helps a lot.